# What is the reason that string stream initialization before getline works, but not the other way around?

Tags: c++

Recently I was doing this:

```cpp
std::string temp = "";
// ...
std::istringstream iss(temp);
std::getline(in, temp);
// ...
while(iss >> my_int) {
    // do this thing
}
```

And it seemed that the string stream was still basically empty, it didn't at all change with the getline..

But instead, doing this:

```cpp
std::getline(in, temp);
std::istringstream iss(temp);
// ...
while(iss >> my_int) {
    // do this thing
}
```

It worked just like I expected. Why don't they both work the same way?

Comment: Do you think that the `stringsteam` is some reference to `temp`? You are initialising the `stringstream` to an empty string, then modifying the string to be something, whereas in the second example you change `temp` to be something, then make the `stringstream` from that something. I'm not sure why you would expect them to behave the same.

Comment: Yeah, you're right I am "initialising the `stringstream` to an empty string, then modifying the string to be something", specifically with that something being stuff from the `in` stream. Is the `stringstream` not a reference to `temp`?

Comment: Have a look into doc. [std::istringstream::istringstream()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream/basic_istringstream): (3) is the one accepting `const std::string&` which is the one used in your samples: _3) Uses a **copy** of str as initial contents of the underlying string device._ (Emphasize mine.) The (`const`) reference might be tempting but is a fooling hint in this case.